# XSSFWorkbook poi: adding image IOUtils toByteArray unfined error

Tags: apache-poi, xssf

To insert image to excel using POI:XSSF
I am using maven poi dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.8</version>
</dependency>
```

AND code as :

```
 InputStream my_banner_image = new FileInputStream("input.png");
 byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(my_banner_image);
 int my_picture_id = wb.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
```

I am getting these errors:

1) The method toByteArray(InputStream) is undefined for the type IOUtils
2) PICTURE_TYPE_PNG cannot be resolved or is not a field

Any help would be appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share the complete stack trace.

Comment: Why are you depending on such an old version of Apache POI? What happens when you specify `3.11` instead? (The latest stable version)

Comment: @Gagravarr: did you try 3.11 ? and have you used XSSF with that?

Comment: @AnkurPiyush: It is a compile error. The method toByteArray(InputStream) is undefined for the type IOUtils

Comment: @guest I, along with huge numbers of others, use POI 3.11 with XSSF without issue

Comment: @Gagravarr:  Even after using POI 3.11 also facing same issue as:                                The method toByteArray(InputStream) is undefined for the type IOUtils

Comment: It [really is there, see the javadocs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/util/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29). Make sure you've imported the correct class  - `org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils`, and don't have any older poi jars on your classpath

Comment: @Gagravarr: thanks. I had some older poi versions, I removed those and worked fine.                                                                                                           One quick question:How can i add multiple fonts to a single cell text. like as the text to fit into cell is: "Some Sample Text string". in this word Text should be bold and underlined  remaining words normal.

Comment: See the third code snippet in [this part of the docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DrawingShapes) - it's done using a [RichTextString](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/RichTextString.html)

Comment: @Gagravarr:  Is poi-contrib(2.5.1-final ) comes in poi 3.11 also?

Comment: You need to delete any POI jars that aren't from the release you're using, so if using POI 3.11 poi-contrib-2.5.1 needs to go. The contrib module was removed some time ago, so just zap the jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer:

The method you want to use is very much present in Apache POI 3.11, and you can see full details about it in the [POI Javadocs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/util/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29).

As detailed on the [POI Components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), defining a Maven dependency on `poi-ooxml` will pull in the main `poi` component jar, which is where the IOUtils class lives, so that bit is fine

What you have in this case (based on comments) is a second, older copy of POI on your classpath. You need to remove this older POI jar (or POI jars), in common with most Java projects Apache POI will only work properly if all of the POI jars are from the same version, and no old ones are present.

Because it's a fairly common problem - lots of frameworks ship old copies of POI for example - there's a [POI FAQ entry on this very thing](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006). If you can't find the old jar by hand, you can use the code given there to work out where the old jar is to remove it.

Also, one other thing to bear in mind - many many projects provide a class called `IOUtils` - make sure the one you have imported into your code is `org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils` and not something else!

Comment: Is poi-contrib(2.5.1-final ) comes in poi 3.11 also?